# Backbone router + coffeescript not working?

Tags: backbone.js, router

+im playing arround with backbone and coffeescript, trying to get the router up and running. executing the following code, the init function works, but when browsing localhost/#world/3 nothing happens, although it should log something....

```
App =
  start: ->
    new App.TestRouter
    Backbone.history.start

App.TestRouter = Backbone.Router.extend
  routes: 
    "world/:id": "testView"

  initialize: ->
    new App.TestView
    console.log "Router init"

  testView: (id) ->
    console.log "testing! #{id}"
```

any advice here? am i blind?

Answer (score 2):

`Backbone.history.start()` is a function, so you need the `()` to execute it.  Otherwise, you're just getting a reference to the function itself.

```
App =
  start: ->
    new App.TestRouter
    Backbone.history.start()
```

See this live jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmsmith/6pNLv/8/

Comment: OT: It's the one reason why I dislike coffeescript. No parens any more!!! Except in certain cases, which you're bound to forget....